# Mirroring a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2d array thus:

```
var array = [
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

What I basically want to do is when a node is changed, e.g.

```
array[3][2] = 1;
```

It changes the opposite side of the array as well, e.g.

```
array[1][2] = 1;
```

**[EDIT]**
Basically, I select a random `x` and random `y` co-ordinate and populate that with a `1`.

I.e.

If I changed one 2 nodes from the left, I want to change the same one 2 nodes from the right.

Comment: What's "the opposite side of the array"?

Comment: As if looking at it in a mirror

Comment: Firstly, I think that is just a 2D array. Secondly, there is no events for the changing of data, so you need a custom function to set the data and make sure this function is always used to update the array

Comment: Updated to say 2d... and updated question

Comment: You keep saying "in a mirror", but a mirror can be placed along any axis of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment, create a function to update the data. Then you can calculate the "opposite side" and update that too:

```
function updateArray(array, x, y, v){
    array[x][y] = v;
    var newX = array.length - 1 - x;
    array[newX][y] = v;
}
```

usage example:

```
updateArray(array, 3, 2, 1);//will set array[3][2] and array[1][2]
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bVnac/)

Comment: I believe this is what I want! Thank you - I already had a (dodgy) function, but this seems correct - thanks!